# shopify transaction api GET all transactions

Tags: rest, api, paypal, shopify

since shopify's transaction reporting is broken, I'm trying to use the API to get transaction fees for orders and basic accounting. In their [API docs](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/transaction#index), they have their endpoints and parameters listed for getting/posting transactions. To "Receive a list of all Transactions", the docs say

```
GET /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.json
```

but don't explain what the `#{id}` is for. The call will only work if I put a transaction ID in, but then it only shows a single transaction, rather than a list. The docs state that to "Get the Representation of a specific transaction":

```
GET /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions/#{id}.json
```

Which has the id in there twice. I can't use a single transaction, I need all of them for a specific range. I've tried `/admin/orders/transactions.json`, or putting in `all` or `*` in for the `id`, and it returns errors unless the id is a valid transaction id. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions belong to an order. So the ID you are wondering about is for one specific order. So if you want transactions for your accounting system, the important thing you're basing your API work on will be orders. So setup your code to first off download the orders of interest. Say for a month. Now for each order ask for the transactions, and produce your report.

Comment: I'm doing it like this as well but their 40 API call limit really bogs this down. If i have over 40 orders then i can't use this approach (I can space out the request in batches of 40 every 2 seconds but that makes for a not very responsive front end). I really wish there was a solution as OP suggests, all transactions regardless of order

Comment: @BelgoCanadian just do your API calls and present an updating progress bar as you chew through your reporting. Most software works this way, and so your App would be normal with this small change. wss:// is your friend here.